# makefile: dependency not build

Tags: makefile

*The question was edited after MadScientist's answer. See history for the original makefile, but the problem stays the same.*

I have a small makefile:

```
DEPFLAGS=-MD -Mo $(OUTDIR)/$*.Td
POSTCOMPILE=@mv -f $(OUTDIR)/$*.Td $(OUTDIR)/$*.d && touch $@
VPATH=../src
OUTDIR=../out
SOURCES:=$(notdir $(wildcard ../src/*.c))
OBJECTS:=$(SOURCES:%.c=$(OUTDIR)/%.o)

all: $(OBJECTS) $(OBJECTS:%.o=%.d)

$(OUTDIR)/%.o : %.c
$(OUTDIR)/%.o : %.c $(OUTDIR)/%.d
    @$(CC) $(DEPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    @$(POSTCOMPILE)

$(OUTDIR)/%.d : ;
.PRECIOUS: $(OUTDIR)/%.d
```

Directory structure looks like:

```
src
  contains file.c
out
  empty, after make: contains file.o and file.d
make
  contains the makefile
```

When I call the makefile everything works fine and two files are generated: *file.o* and *file.d*

However, when I delete *file.d* nothing happens. I would expect that make finds a missing dependency for *file.c* and starts a rebuild. Why doesn't it happen?

Make version is 3.81 built for i386-pc-mingw32 under Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marking a file as `.PRECIOUS` does not remove all aspects of it's "intermediateness".  All it does is prevent it from being deleted, but this feature of [intermediate files](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html) is still in effect:

> If an ordinary file b does not exist, and make considers a target that depends on b, it invariably creates b and then updates the target from b. But if b is an intermediate file, then make can leave well enough alone. It won’t bother updating b, or the ultimate target, unless some prerequisite of b is newer than that target or there is some other reason to update that target.

This is why your `.d` file is not recreated.  In order for it to be recreated you need to ensure it's not an intermediate file.  Fortunately this is trivial to do: you just need to mention the files explicitly somewhere as a target or prerequisite.  You can do it like this:

```
all: $(OBJECTS) $(SOURCES:%.c=$(OUTDIR)/%.d)
```

Or if you prefer like this:

```
depends: $(SOURCES:%.c=$(OUTDIR)/%.d)
```

which would allow you to run `make depends` to update the dependency files, if you wanted to.

I'll just point out in passing that this method of managing dependencies is considered outdated.  There's a better, more advanced way it can be done [described here](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) among other places.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it still does not work. I updated my makefile (see question) according to the page you linked. And I added a prerequisite for my all-target. However when I delete the dependency file still nothing happens. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know, I just tried it and it works for me, using GCC 7.2 on GNU/Linux, with GNU make 4.2.1.  I did have to modify the compiler arguments to create dependencies because the ones you are using are not correct for this version of GCC (the `-Mo` option is not recognized).  I used the ones in the blog.  Also, it's weird that you don't actually `include` the generated `.d` files since that's the entire point of generating them but that shouldn't cause the problems you're seeing.

Comment: I *strongly* recommend you REMOVE the `@` flags that suppress printing the scripts.  You'd not believe how many problems happen because people mistype variables, etc. so their command lines are wrong but they never see it because they're suppressing the printing of their recipes.  Adding `@`, if done at all (I don't use it) should only be added as the very last step after every other aspect of the build system is already working and debugged.  You might also consider the idea presented here: http://make.mad-scientist.net/managing-recipe-echoing/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Since it works for you, I replaced make 3.8 with 4.2.1 and voila - it works for me, too :) Seems to be a problem with make 3.8. Btw. I include the dep files, I just tried to strip everything that is not related to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

(I'll be a horrific necromancer here, but I've ran into same problem, and found that actual issue isn't one mentioned in answer or comments here)

Dependency rule generated by compiler by default sports file name with ALL suffixes replaced by single suffix  .o *and path removed*. Which doesn't match the pattern of rule in makefile.

For gcc 4.x and later correct options would be

```
$(OUTDIR)/%.o : %.c $(OUTDIR)/%.d
      @$(CC) -MF $(OUTDIR)/$*.Td -MT $@ -c $< -o $@
```

Mo flag no longer exist, you have to use only MF flag to specify dependency file name.MT flag allows to provide a literal line for target name.

Comment: thaks for your solution, really helped me a lot